# Angular route resolver .NET Core 2 server side prerendering

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, asp-net-core-spa-services

I have an Angular v4 application generated from the .NET Core 2 Angular template.

The template uses server side prerendering.

I am trying to use a route resolver to get data before navigating to a page displaying a table of images (or rather image records).

Whenever I try to use a resolver I get a NodeInvocationException from server side prerendering.

<strike>Do I need to supply the full path (include host name) in the HTTP get URL for this to work?</strike>

See updates at bottom for question.

**images.resolver.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { ImageModel } from './image.model';
import { ImagesService } from './images.service';

@Injectable()
export class ImagesResolver implements Resolve<ImageModel[]> {

    constructor(private imagesService: ImagesService) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> {
        return this.imagesService.list();
    }
}
```

**images.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ImagesService {

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    list(): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.get(`api/images`);
    }

    get(id: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.get(`api/images/${id}`);
    }

    save(model: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.post(`api/images`, model);
    }

    update(model: any): Observable<any> | null {
        return null;
    }

    delete(id: number): Observable<any> | null {
        return null;
    }

}
```

**images-routing.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ImagesComponent } from './images.component';
import { ImageListComponent } from './image-list/image-list.component';
import { ImageComponent } from './image/image.component';

import { ImageResolver } from './shared/image.resolver';
import { ImagesResolver } from './shared/images.resolver';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ImagesComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: ImageListComponent,
                resolve: {
                    images: ImagesResolver
                }
            },
            {
                path: ':id',
                component: ImageComponent,
                resolve: {
                    image: ImageResolver
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class ImagesRoutingModule { }

export const routedComponents = [
    ImagesComponent,
    ImageListComponent,
    ImageComponent
];
```

**Update**

I have attempted to append the base URL for the API endpoint in the images service but to no avail. I still get the same error.

```js
constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string
) { }

list(): Observable<any> {        
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.baseUrl}api/images`);
}
```

After a bit of digging I found this in the error information:

> Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error

I believe that this message comes from Angular's HttpClient but I don't know why I am getting this.

The complete endpoint I am trying to access is:

https://localhost:44317/api/images/featured

**Another Update**

I have found that everything works okay with SSL disabled. I do not want to leave this disabled.

How can I configure angular universal / node / spa services to work with SSL while server side prerendering?

Comment: It might help to break up your app into a separate projects. The .net core spa templates seem nice, but they do have their quirks. One being that it outputs invalid html, which may have a negative effect on SEO (the only reason to use ssr, in my opinion). Another thing to consider is that Angular 5 is scheduled to be released in a few days/weeks from the time of me writing this. V5 is also supposed to have lots of improvements for SSR. I guess what I'm saying is that with separate projects, it's pretty easy to update ng and isolate these errors if they show up.

Comment: You raise a good point. To be honest the part of the spa I'm having trouble with is used for content management which could be split out into it's own app. And then I suppose it wouldn't require seo considerations, and I could leave the client facing side where seo is important using ssr.

Comment: Yup, just what I was thinking - you  have the cms admin as a full-blown spa and then use regular mvc controllers to display the actual content with razor pages.So 2 separate projects and would also make it easier from a security standpoint (everything rendered by mvc razor is open to anyone and all the api controllers for the spa have the authorize attribute). Subdomian your spa to something like admin.yoursite.com and the content would be similar to yoursite.com/content. Just some thoughts.

Comment: Or (with 2 separate projects) you could just keep everything angular for your site. When youdo this, you can pick and choose which pages you want to use ssr (using universal).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking @DJDJ's advice and split the app up into two parts.

> It might help to break up your app into a separate projects. The .net core spa templates seem nice, but they do have their quirks. One being that it outputs invalid html, which may have a negative effect on SEO (the only reason to use ssr, in my opinion). Another thing to consider is that Angular 5 is scheduled to be released in a few days/weeks from the time of me writing this. V5 is also supposed to have lots of improvements for SSR. I guess what I'm saying is that with separate projects, it's pretty easy to update ng and isolate these errors if they show up.

I have not yet tried the same thing using Angular 5 but I have had success on another project with SSR and Angular 5.